# Android application fuzzing

Tags: android, fuzzing

How to do fuzzing in Android applications? Do we have any fuzzer specific to the android?

Actually, I am looking for an easy way to do fuzzing while performing penetration testing of android applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fork of AFL fuzzer that is specialized in Android fuzzing. You can find it on GitHub. And, there are several fuzzing frameworks specialized for Android.

#### References

- [Andoid-afl](https://github.com/ele7enxxh/android-afl).
- [Fuzzing with libFuzzer](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/libfuzzer).
- [Droid: Android application fuzzing framework](https://github.com/ajinabraham/Droid-Application-Fuzz-Framework).
- [Writing the worlds worst Android fuzzer, and then improving it](https://gamozolabs.github.io/fuzzing/2018/10/18/terrible_android_fuzzer.html), by Gamozo 2018.
- [Fuzzing Android: a recipe for uncovering vulnerabilities inside system components in Android](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-15/materials/eu-15-Blanda-Fuzzing-Android-A-Recipe-For-Uncovering-Vulnerabilities-Inside-System-Components-In-Android-wp.pdf), by Alexandru Blanda (BlackHat'15).
- [DoApp (Denial of App): A smart Android Fuzzer for the future](http://www.iswatlab.eu/security-projects/doapp-denial-of-app-a-smart-android-fuzzer-for-the-future/).
- [Droid-FF](https://github.com/antojoseph/droid-ff).
- [AFL-unicorn1](https://firmwaresecurity.com/2017/11/09/afl-unicorn-fuzz-any-architecture-supported-by-unicorn/) and [AFL-unicorn2](http://cn-sec.com/archives/146342.html)
- [AFL++ with QEMU for native android fuzzing](https://alephsecurity.com/2021/11/16/fuzzing-qemu-android/):  This is a modification of the original [AFLplusplus](https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus) so as to able to fuzz binary-only Android applications using QEMU and running inside native Android environment.

Comment: Is there any other approach I can follow do fuzz the apps without using any tool? If the tools are only the options is there any other free tools with better documentation & examples?

Comment: You can try the "[Monkey testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_testing)" with real Monkeys... apart from that I do not understand quite well how you can perform efficient fuzzing without any tool!